# Android & AdMob: When to call AdView.loadAd

Tags: android, admob, oncreate, onresume

when is the "best moment" to load a new ad from AdMob?

I'm programming a shopping list application that has an admob banner on its main screen.

First I called

```
 m_AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

in the the onCreate() method. But so I always got displayed the same ad.

Now I want to put the call into onResume(). But isn't there the chance to cause too much network traffic?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to load the `adMob` is in the `onCreate()`. So, I would just leave it in the `onCreate()` method. Don't worry about what ad is being displayed as it is what the adMob api is telling it to display. It may be in testing mode, so when you go to run it "live", it will change. The fact that you are getting an ad means it is working.

Here is what I did with my app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(re);
 ...
```

Comment: I did not find any information on this topic in the offical admob docs or anywhere else. But in all code sniplets loadAd is called in OnCreate.
But why is onCreate the best place?

Comment: Because `onCreate` is where the app is created. If you put it in `onResume` you aren't putting in the "beginning". Here is a link to the lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html Hopefully this will explain it a little better. Basically you want to start the admob app when you start the app.

Comment: This is the question: Should I put it in the beginning or not.I am familiar with the life cycle!

Comment: Yes, you should. That way it is always called on the creation.

Answer (score 0):

the official documentation tells to put the loadAd() into onCreate(), since you also have to register AdActivity in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"/>
```

I guess it will stick to the lifecycle of your main activity hence handling onPause() and onResume() properly.

**EDIT**

According to [admob sample](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play) you have to delegate lifecycles calls to AdView instance.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering the same (talking about Banner not Interstitial )

Most examples I found on the net 
load the request (`adView.loadAd(new AdRequest())`)   in `onCreate`.

but can be `onStart`:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(adView != null) {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```

according:
[AdMob ad in onCreate OK, but disappears if you return to activity, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718233/admob-ad-in-oncreate-ok-but-disappears-if-you-return-to-activity-why)

In Activity life cycle, `OnStart` is called just after `onCreate`

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

so... I thing sound good place too

Comment: No. Whatever they say about ad initialization in onResume applies to onStart too. OnStart is called after onCreate, but it may also be called without onCreate.